# Splitting sheet text using an array to mantain unique ID

Tags: javascript, arrays, for-loop, google-apps-script, google-sheets

I'm using this: [How to transpose and split in Google Apps Script?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/57549459/how-to-transpose-and-split-in-google-apps-script)

Which works great in the first part (I use it to copy data an split it) but then I would need to redo it since I have 2 different separators, first time ";" second time ",".

The issue and I'm guessing it's more JS related than anything else, is that if I use the same for it splits the 2nd column vertically. I'll post examples.

[image: Column A has the ID, Column B has the comma separated text]

If I use it again to reformat it gives this:

[image]

I would like it to be split into Column B and C.

I figured it was because the for loop only pushes 2 rows, but I can't solve adding a third.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

### ****Issue:****

If I understood it correctly, you have something like this:

[image]

And you would like to end up with something like this:

[image]

---

### ****Solution:****

The following code will do just that, splitting (and putting into several lines) the values in the first image by `;`, and then separating the quantity from the product name (accomplished by splitting the `,`).

```js
function myFunction() {
  
  var spreadsheet = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet();
  var sheet = spreadsheet.getSheetByName("Sheet1");

  var range = sheet.getRange(2,1,sheet.getLastRow()-1,2);
  var values = range.getValues();

  var valuesToInput = [];

  for(var i = 0; i<values.length; i++){
    var productList = values[i][1].split(";");
    
    for(var j = 0; j < productList.length; j++){
      var productVariables = productList[j].split(",");
      var productQuantity = productVariables[0];
      var productName = productVariables[1];

      valuesToInput.push([values[i][0], productQuantity, productName]);
    }
  }

  var rangeToInput = sheet.getRange(2,1,valuesToInput.length, 3);
  rangeToInput.setValues(valuesToInput);
}
```

Comment: Can't test it out right now, but I'm fairly confident it would work. I'll check tomorrow when I have access to the GAS account.

Comment: Hi, It works a bit, had to do a little modification (not to the code, just to input the resulting array into another sheet), the only issue is that it gives some 'underfined' with blank spaces inbetween the data and at the last rows. https://pastebin.com/PqtrcfFM < the modified code.

The issue:
https://pastebin.com/Ah1TcBBk